# What is proper way to share API TS types though microservices (via npm)?

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack, microservices, nestjs

I have an issue while implementing my microservice network. The situation is next: I just finished the first microservice (let it be `micro-A`) and now I start working on another one (`micro-B`). I realize that I need to share DTO and some interfaces from `micro-A` to use them in `micro-B`. Because I need type-safe communication between them. I've investigated half of the internet and I didn't find an answer to this situation. 
There are two ways of how people do this - using monorepo and npm packages. I'd like to use npm packages. So at this point, I decided to create a separate folder (let's name it `api-interfaces`) in my microservice where I will create index.ts file with such code:

```
export * from './src/users/dto/profile.res.dto';
export * from './src/users/dto/user.res.dto';
```

And then create a webpack config, which will copy all dependencies for `api-interfaces/index.ts`  to `api-interfaces/lib/*`, and then publish it to npm.
Looks Ok, but then I got next errors:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@nestjs/swagger' in '/micro-user/src/profiles/dto'
 @ ../profiles/dto/profile.res.dto.ts 14:18-44
 @ ../users/dto/user.res.dto.ts
 @ ./index.ts

ERROR in ../profiles/dto/profile.res.dto.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'class-transformer' in '/micro-user/src/profiles/dto'
 @ ../profiles/dto/profile.res.dto.ts 13:28-56
 @ ../users/dto/user.res.dto.ts
 @ ./index.ts
```

Also, I use serialization via class-transformer. So at this moment, I stuck ...
I've two questions:
 - do you have any idea how to share API DTOs and Interfaces between microservices?
 - can you help me with my webpack build?